# Can a value or text string inside a Shortcut be changed by an external mechanism (e.g., a script)?

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

Our team is creating Shortcuts to automate some procedures. Those Shortcuts will evolve as we find bugs and release new versions. I would like to put information about the version of a given Shortcut *into the Shortcut itself*, to make it easier to determine which version someone was running when they (e.g.) encountered a problem.

So far the only way I have found of storing information like that is to use a Comment or Dictionary within the Shortcuts, at the top, to record the values. Here's an example:
[image]
In other software contexts, I would use a Makefile or script or other automation to update the value inside a file when making a release for distribution to other people. However, I haven't been able to figure out a way to automate the process for Shortcuts. When exported, the Shortcut files are in a binary format and (maybe?) are signed, and I haven't found a way to edit values inside shortcuts after exporting them.

*Is* there any way to either (1) change the value in an exported Shortcut file, or (2) use a script or automation to update the value when exporting the Shortcut from the Shortcuts app?

My fallback approach is to put the version into the file name of the Shortcut file. If there's a way to write it inside the file itself, that would be preferable, but only if I don't have to remember to update the value manually when releasing new versions.